# Resource with a single attribute. Sign that something smells?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, activerecord

I have a book model and a notes model. Each book can have many notes.

```
# note.rb
id | book_id | content | page_number | author_id |
```

I want to run a lot of queries like

1. Get all the notes for page 43 of a certain book
2. Show all the noted pages of a certain book

These types of queries seem to favor making a separate noted_pages model so that a book can have many noted_pages and each noted_page can have many notes. This is fine but my noted_pages table would effectively just have an id column and a page_number column which doesn't sit right with me.

Is there a more standard way to implement this kind of setup or is my thinking ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A noted_page table would relate notes to pages, but do you need a page table?

If you need a page table, then yes, worry about the note<->page many-to-many relationship and create a link table. If you don't need to store book_pages as rows of a table, then don't.

Your design:
id | book_id | content | page_number | author_id |

Will give you the answers you want by querying like this:

1. Get all the notes for page 43 of a certain book

   select *
   from note
   where book_id=123 and page_number=43;
2. Show all the noted pages of a certain book

   select page_number, count(id)
   from note where book_id=123
   group by page_number;

If performance is an issue then put an index on the page number. You could also make (id, book_id, page_number) into a composite key, so your data will store (note 3, book 123, page 43).

Comment: Most of the answers on this question helped me with my problem but I'm accepting this one because it best describes what I ended up doing and I'm happy with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a many to many relationship, as in a book can have many notes, and notes can have many books, you must have a join table like you stated.

It would look like:

```
noted_page
--------------
id   book_id note_id
```

This is just general practice, whenever you have a many-to-many relationship you MUST have a join table.

(Some frameworks/orm's don't require you to have a `id` column, but as far as I know, Rails/ActiveRecord does require it.)

Comment: It's not really a many to many relationship I'm going for. Each note would only ever be associated with one book. My question is really if it's worthwhile defining the extra noted_pages model or can I use scopes or some other technique to my advantage instead?

Answer (score 0):

No design is bad ... it just need to be justified.

I see different solutions :

1. A `BOOK` {title, author, edited_date ...} has many `PAGE` {content} has_many `NOTES` {note_content}
2. A `BOOK` {**content**, title, author, edited_date ...} has_many `NOTES` {note_content, page_number}

It depends on how you work with the book. Do you plan on saving the content of the book by pages or not ? If not, then can you find the page, and therefore the notes ?

Regarding your questions :

- A model with one attribute is not the sign that it "smells". You can even have a 1-to-1 relationship, if it's justifier.
- There's no "standard" way of implementing stuff. Like I said, it depends on how you work, on how you plan your users to use it (UI-wised), how you would store, etc....
- You definatly won't need a many-to-many in your case ... rails provide enough tools t fetch from a model to its associations, w/ w/o conditions, etc...

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I'm quitting the internet because of this unexplained downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'd guess someone objected to "No design is bad, it just needs to be justified." There are *lots* of bad designs--truly wretched, brain-dead designs--out in the wild. Probably millions of them.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these can be simple ARel queries, no scope is required

The latter one is a simple check of the existence of the notes collection:

```
@book.notes.empty? #if there are no notes, it'll return true and vice versa
```

To get the book notes for a certain page:

```
@book.notes.where(["page_number = ?", page_number]) #where page_number is a variable, possibly a parameter
```

However, I do think you need to think through how you're going to model your data. Marcel has a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Your design is fine.  Don't over normalize.  You'll probably just want to put an index on `book_id, page_number` on your notes table so you can do the lookup efficiently.